# how to get id of the imagesource of image like getImageResource 

Tags: android, image

I am working on Application in which I want to access the id of image from R.java which is used by imageView. 
for examle

```
imageView i;
i=(ImageView)findViewbyid(imageview1);
i.setImageResource(R.drawble.human); 
.....
```

now i want to know which id is used by i in running application.

Comment: As per srikanth's comment i also don't understood your question. you must clearify your question and put the code which you try for this.

Comment: Describe briefly your question.

Comment: what u want be clear not go round and round and so on...

Answer (score 0):

//when you place an image in you drawable it will generate an Id in R.java file

when you want that particular image to display in your ImageView

you need to declare like this

```
public static Integer[] images = new Integer[]{R.drawable.my_love,R.drawable.first,R.drawable.second,R.drawable.third};
```

And then set the image resource like this,

```
ImageView i = new ImageView(this.context);
i.setImageResource(this.images[1]);
```

//you have declared as

```
imageView i=(ImageView)findViewbyid(imageview1);
```

//what is this imageview1?

instead of that you need to give your xml declaration ImageView id as

```
 imageView i=(ImageView)findViewbyid(R.id.imageview);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a method to get the Image Background of a ImageView this will help you.

```
   ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
       imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
      imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
      Drawable d=imageView.getBackground();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the id of the image in drawable

```
String mDrawableName =Integer.toString( R.drawable.human);              
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
```